# Dynamically variable's level selection in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app which will ask users to select n number of  character variable from a pre-loaded data frame through select input widget. For simplicity a data frame is created with two character variables only(category and brand).

If user selects one character variable say category then one more widget appears dynamically prompting to select levels of category. If he selects two character variable i.e. category and brand both then two input widget appears dynamically prompting to select levels of both.

In category variable I have two levels (skin-care and hair-care) and their brands are of course different.

The challenge is when user selects both in 1st input widgets and skin care in 2nd input widget I want only skin care brand to be displayed as option in 3rd input widget and if hair care in  2nd input widget then only hair care brands in 3rd input widgets. If both selected in 2nd input widgets then only all brand should come as option in 3rd input widgets.

I am struggling with these and not able to do in any other way also.
Please suggest.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Data", fluid = TRUE,
         sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(p("Please remove None first"),
                        uiOutput("dim"),
                        uiOutput("levels1")),
           mainPanel(
             DT::dataTableOutput("data_display")
           ))))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

# creating Data 
data <- reactive({
data <-  data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2018-05-25","2018-05-26")),
                    category = c(rep("skin_care",6),rep("hair_care",6)),
                    Brand = 

c("X","X","Y","Y","Z","Z","A","A","B","B","C","C"),sales = 
                      round(rnorm(12,100,3)))
})


# Displaying Data  

output$data_display <- DT::renderDataTable(                    
datatable(data(),options = list(pageLength = 12),rownames = FALSE)
)

# selects dimension (Only character variable to be selected)

output$dim<-renderUI({
b<-colnames(data()[sapply(data(),class)=="character"])
selectInput("x","Select only character variable",choices = 
              c("NONE",b[1:length(b)]),selected="NONE",multiple = TRUE)
})

#  user selects levels of dimension 

output$levels1<-renderUI({
if(is.null(input$x)){
  return(NULL)
}
 else if(sum(input$x=="NONE")==1){
   return(NULL)
 }
else{
  lapply(seq(input$x),function(i){
    selectInput(inputId = paste0("range",i),
          paste0("Select level of ",input$x[i]),
        choices = c(unique(data()[,input$x[i]]),"ALL"),multiple = TRUE)

  })
}
  })
  })

  shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Will the variables always be those two, or are you looking for a generic solution? What should happen if I select `Brand` first? Should it still be filtered from the category input or is now `category` that is filtered by `brand`?

Comment: @GGamba variables can be any number. For simplicity i kept two. Ideally user should select category first and then brand in hierarchical order.